# Laravel files throwing error when file is too large (Nginx, Azure App Service)

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have recently upgraded to PHP 8 on Azure which replaced Apache2 with NGINX. I am now experiencing a lot of issues.

I am trying to write to a path inside of Laravel based on the files contents:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::append($path, request()->file('file')->get());
```

I see this error on larger files:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException File does not exist at path.

If I `dd` the `request()->file('file')` I see the following:

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#4194
  -test: false
  -originalName: "blob"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -error: 1
  #hashName: null
  path: ""
  filename: ""
  basename: ""
  pathname: ""
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/home/site/wwwroot/public"
  aTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  mTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  cTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  inode: false
  size: false
  perms: 00
  owner: false
  group: false
  type: false
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: false
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

The error is thrown on the `->get()`. This tells me that the file is not saving correctly to the `/tmp` directory PHP is using. To this effect, I altered my nginx configuration to contain the following:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

I restarted nginx so the changes would take effect but I still recieve this error.

Is there something I need in my `php.ini` or configure inside of Azure?

If I upload a file of `45368` bytes it works fine, if I upload one with `278712` bytes it works fine, if I upload one with `5712115` I get the error.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you need to tweak PHP settings. do `phpinfo()` and echeck max post size and max upload size

Comment: It cant even find the file in `path`. It is not about the size

Comment: It can't find the file in the `path` because the file is never uploaded post 5mb file sizes @VüsalHüseynli

Comment: Thanks, I'm tryna figure out how to override this in azure now, it is the php.ini that is very low by default as you've indicated @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: If your environment is linux then first run `php --ini` command to see which `php.ini`  file you are using. You might change wrong one

Comment: Thanks @VüsalHüseynli - Azure is being an asbolute nightmare around this, so instead, I used your method to just locate the current configuration directory and cp my custom php into it named `custom.ini` but it isn't taking the change into effect even if I restart nginx -.-

Comment: You will need to restart `php-fpm` as well or just `php`

Answer (score 0):

After some further research around the comments raised on this post, I found the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux#customize-php_ini_system-directives).

When running the said `php --ini` command, you'll see `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d` is listed in there. Changing your `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` to another directoy looses all this configuration/drivers so you'll need to instead use an additonal `:` to specify a new directory. I created one in my repo to persist this across all the deployment servers.

My directory is `php` which contains `custom.ini` and then my `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` is configured to:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d:/home/site/wwwroot/php
```